# iOS: Run code only after it's been added to the home screen

Tags: ios, icons

I'd like know if there's away to run a bit of code only after it's been installed to the home screen on iOS. This is for internal use only so I don't need it to work on other platforms. Just iOS.

Basically, I want to add a few **custom** icons to iOS devices that do specific things. One will open a PDF and that's the one I'm having a hard time working with.

So, here's the flow...

User goes to URL on their iOS based device, there is nothing to see here, but then they add the URL to their home screen. Once they click on the home screen icon, the page opens and redirects to the a PDF that lives online. The pdf can live online since they will always have wifi.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this for a jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: No. Must work on a regular iOS device.

Comment: I don't think Apple would let you do this, and I don't know of any ways to do this.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It seems like such a simple thing to do, but I haven't been able to find a way.